# How to create a shopify product with many variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, shopify, ruby-on-rails-5

Anyone knows how to create new products with variants?

In the Ruby on Rails world, we have our `:has_many`, then do this:

```
Product.create!(...).variants.build(...).save
```

That would create a product and its association `variant`.

For Shopify, I have no idea:

```
user_products.map do | up |
  new_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.build(...)

  up.variants.each do |variant|
   new_products.variants.build(...)
  end

  new_products.save
end
```

Doing just that I got:

> ActiveResource::ServerError (Failed.  Response code = 501.  Response message = Not Implemented.)

In my case, this is not ideal:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.new(
 {
  ...,
  variants: [
   ...
  ]
 }
).save
```

Comment: You'll have to adjust your use case to reality. When the world does not come in your flavour, you adjust. Mapping your RoR approach to the actual REST API approach is what, 2 minutes of work?

Comment: How are you structuring your array objects inside variants. Follow proper schema in official documentation and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify do not support variants as nested objects.
You will need to create a REST request per each variant you want to create.
Please refer to variant object documentation

Shopify API for variant:
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product_variant

and also be sure you are using Shopify gem for that:
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api

Comment: Sorry. Im not fully understanding what you are saying and how that code would look.